# Database design for queries that has tons of sql-like join

Tags: mongodb, join, database-design, database

I have a collection named `posts` consisting of multiple article posts and a collection called `users` which has a lot of user info.  Each `post` has a field called `author` that references the post author in the `users` collection.

On my home page I will query the `posts` collection and return a list of posts to the client. Since I also want to display the author of the post I need to do sql-like join commands so that all the posts will have author names, ids,...etc.

If I return a list of 40 posts I'd have to do 40 sqllike-joins. Which means each time I will do 41 queries to get a list of posts with author info.  Which just seems really expensive.

I am thinking to store the author info at the time I am storing the post info.  This way I only need to do 1 query to retrieve all posts and author info.  However when the user info changes (such as name changes) the list will be outdated and it seems not quite easy to manage lists like this.

So is there's a better or standard approach to this?

p.s: I am using mongodb

Comment: There is a whole section of common examples and cases in the core documentation. [Data Modelling](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/data-modeling-introduction/)

Comment: yes thanks just that I was just making the problem really simple. the actual case is quite complicated with 1 user profile linked to multiple attributes like pagelikes, reviews, checkins...

Comment: like for example the above 40 posts are by the same author. when the author changes name you only need to update the posts 40 times.  which seems cheap (to me).  But I am not sure if there's a more general approach for this..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mongo is NoSQL DB. By definition, NoSQL solutions are meant to be denormalized(all required data should be located at a same location)

In your example, relationship between authors and posts is one to many but ratio of authors as compared to posts is very small. In simple words, no. of authors as compared to no. of posts will be very small.

Based on this, you can safely store author info in posts collection.

If you need to query posts collection i.e. if you know your most queries will be executed on posts collection then it makes sense to store author in posts. It wont take huge space to store one attribute but it will make huge difference in query performance and easiness to code/retrieve the data.

Comment: what if the author changes his name? should I loop over the entire post collection and update that author info accordingly?

Comment: also one author is possibly to have 1000 posts.  In this case when he updates his name 3 times in a row then that's 3000 writes.  So does that mean I am possibly giving people the opportunity to bring down the server easily?

Comment: If author changes his name, single update query (with author name in find clause)will update the name everywhere. You don't have to iterate (similar to RDBMS)

Comment: First of all, Changing name doesn't happen so frequently. it happens once in a while which can be handled 
Second, a single user will have 100-200 posts on an average. so changing name once in a while for 100-1000 posts won't bring down the server. (I am hoping you have atleast server class hw :) )

Comment: that makes sense actually.

Comment: I am still thinking about the details in a while and it is indeed helpful. :)

Comment: ya seems no matter how complicated the schema is as long as I keep a id I should be able to update the collections. just a lot of work though..